# How can i get page URL in single-approver-definition.xml in Kaleo workflow in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, workflow

How can i get the page URL in `single-approver-definition.xml` in the e-mail template that is used to send an e-mail to the content creator once the reviewer approves or rejects the submission. The existing xml is as follows:

```
<template>
    Your submission has been reviewed and the reviewer has applied the following: 
    ${taskComments}.
</template>
```

I tried `${serviceContext.getAttribute("contentURL")}` and it didn't work.

I want to be able to do - `Your submission for ${pageURL} has been reviewed and the reviewier has applied the following: \n ${taskComments}.\n`

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what variable exactly you want to process in your notification. As I can only assume, you are using it for Web Contents and all interesting variables are stored in two places.

1. Workflow context variables - they are available directly. Few examples like:

   > - ${taskComments}
   > - ${entryType}
   > - ${userId}
   > - ${userName}
   > - ...
2. ServiceContext variables - they are available using $serviceContext. Few examples:

   > - $serviceContext.getAttributes().get("version")
   > - $serviceContext.getAttributes().get("articleId")
   > - ${serviceContext.getPortalURL()}
   > - ...

For all interesting variables check this url https://www.liferay.com/web/igor.beslic/blog/-/blogs/workflow-in-action-kaleo-workflow-context-variables Some could change already, however most of them is working fine for current version.

Comment: Thanks Tomic, that's great info. I want to get the URL of the page where the content creator made the changes and submitted them for review. Once the reviewer has reviewed those changes, an e-mail is sent to the creator saying that his submission has been approved/rejected and that is where i want to include the URL of the page so that the creator can just click on it. I think i need to use "articleURL" for that. What do you think?

Comment: Actually 'articleURL' will give you url to control panel, where you can see this web content article in edit mode. I doubt you can achieve url, redirecting you to place where this web content is displayed for user. Reasons of that are two. Firstly, only published Web Contents are displayed, so you wouldn't see any changes even if it was possible. Second, articles are presented using Web Content Display portlet and single article can be displayed in multiple pages, which one should be returned then? Still this articleURL is closest one you can achieve already.

Comment: Anther hint which I can give you is passing url to current revisions processed by this user. Here is code you need to pass in notification <a href="${serviceContext.getPortalURL()}/group/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=153" >Check all your revisions</a>

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I have the workflow enabled for pages and not the web-content. So when the content creator adds or removes a new portlet or web-content to the page, then those changes are not published until the reviewer approves/rejects them. That is where i am trying to get the URL of the page. If creator makes any changes to an existing web-content, then the workflow is "not" triggered as i have disabled that.

Answer (score 1):

Content changes *might* be made on a page, they can also be triggered through Control Panel (or the API for that matter). When you're in a workflow, you typically don't have this context any more - if you find it somehow I'd not rely on it to be there. A workflow is unrelated to the UI and pages.

Also, an article might be submitted on one page, where it might be replaced/removed before it's even approved. In that case the link wouldn't help.

What might work is to check the concept behind "Web Content Display Pages" (if your article has them configured and you deal with web content). But the mechanics will vary depending on the actual content type you're dealing with. And content that goes through workflow might not be displayed on any page at all (e.g. when submitted through Control Panel) or on many different pages (either explicitly - Web Content Display - or implicitly - Asset Publisher).

@tomic basically provides pointers to what you have, I'm only reasoning why your initial problem is problematic to solve at best - it's not fully specifiable.